# requests.get is slow with images

Tags: python

This downloads 20 images from Github & it takes around 57 seconds to run.
When I ran this on another PC in with a different internet connection I got the same results
is there any way to speed it up?

the images are ~1 MB

```
def loadImage(url, Finger):
    response = requests.get(url)
    image = np.asarray(bytearray(response.content), dtype="uint8")
    image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

    if Finger:
        image = cv2.resize(image,(320, 550))
    else:
        image = cv2.resize(image,(127,127))

    return image

class Finerprint:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fingerImg = []
        self.fingerSol = [None] * 4


fingerprints = [None] * 4


def initFingerprints():
    # Initialize the four fingerprints
    for i in range(4):
        fingerprints[i] = Finerprint()
        fingerprints[i].fingersol = []

    for i in range(4):
        print(f"Loading F{i}")
        fingerprints[i].fingerImg = loadImage(f"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HazemMohamed98/GTA-Online-Fingerprint/Images/F{i + 1}.jpg", True)
        for j in range(4):
            print(f"Loading F{i}S{j}")
            fingerprints[i].fingerSol[j] = loadImage(f"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HazemMohamed98/GTA-Online-Fingerprint/Images/F{i + 1}S{j + 1}.jpg", False)

initFingerprints()
```

Comment: You could use multiprocessing to send the requests for the image downloads all at once. Look up the Pool function in the multiprocessing.dummy library.

Comment: Line ```fingerprints[i],fingersol = []``` needs to be ```fingerprints[i].fingerSol = [None] * 4```, else you get ```index out of range``` when you address ```fingerprints[i].fingerSol[j] =...```. I ran this on a 300 mb/s connection, it ran in 5.81 seconds.  This points to internet connectivity.  so @PL200's suggestion to multi-processing solution as likely th target to speed up the process

Comment: Look into multiprocessing, threading, or asyc. The idea is that you want to download them all in parallel instead of serially so that you can saturate your internet connection.

Comment: Yeah multiprocessing seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Brendan Abel's suggestion inspired me to try out some `multiprocessing` on this.  I came up with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import cv2
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
import numpy as np
import requests
from time import time

f_count = 4
s_count = 4

def loadImage(response, Finger):
    image = np.asarray(bytearray(response.content), dtype="uint8")
    image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

    if Finger:
        image = cv2.resize(image,(320, 550))
    else:
        image = cv2.resize(image,(127,127))

    return image

def build_URL(f=0, s=None):
    url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HazemMohamed98/GTA-Online-Fingerprint/Images/"
    insert = f'F{f}' + (f'S{s}' if s is not None else '')
    return f'{url}{insert}.jpg'

def fetch_all(rf, rs):
    urls = [build_URL(i+1) for i in range(rf)] + [build_URL(i+1,j+1) for i in range(rf) for j in range(rs)]
    t = time()
    with ThreadPool(20) as pool:
        responses = list(pool.map(requests.get, urls))
    t = time() - t
    print(f'Parallel fetch time: {t} sec')
    return responses

class Fingerprint:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fingerImg = []
        self.fingerSol = [None] * s_count


fingerprints = [None] * f_count


def initFingerprints():
    # Acquire all URLs in parallel
    responses = fetch_all(f_count, s_count)
    # Initialize the four fingerprints
    ndx = f_count
    for i in range(f_count):
        fingerprints[i] = Fingerprint()

    for i in range(f_count):
        print(f"{i} Loading image from {responses[i].url}")
        fingerprints[i].fingerImg = loadImage(responses[i], True)
        for j in range(s_count):
            print(f"{i} {j} {ndx} Loading image from {responses[ndx].url}")
            fingerprints[i].fingerSol[j] = loadImage(responses[ndx], False)
            ndx += 1
    return fingerprints
```

Note that I have left in the parts where the indexes for the loops are printed along with which url is being assigned to what after the fetch operation.  I have no practical way of examining the results of `cv2`, I was aiming only to see what the results are using the multiprocessing.

In my tests, the actual time to fetch all 20 URLs in parallel was between 0.3 and 0.6 seconds. That it a vast improvement over the serial ~6 seconds results.

Well this has been very educational for me, I hope it will be of use to the OP!

Comment: This is pure gold. the runtime became 12 seconds for me instead of the old 57 seconds. I am guessing my internet connection is still a bottleneck.

I will probably make it so that the photos get stored locally after the first time so that there's no need to re-download them every run.

Comment: Glad this helped.  (I know I am totally spoiled here for internet speed...). Thanks to @Brendan Abel for the suggestion and inspiration.